# exception 'Drush\User\UserListException' with message Unable to find a matching user for admin

Tags: gitlab, drupal-7, git-bash, drupal-8, drupal-views

I am using the drupal7 I have been executed this command in git bash -`./prepare_db_for_dev.example.sh`

In below, it give error.

```
Reset admin password to "admin".
Drush\User\UserListException: Unable to find a matching user for admin. 
In C:\Users\patil.vaish\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush\lib\Drush\User\UserList.php:114             [error]
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\patil.vaish\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush\lib\Drush\User\UserList.php(15): Drush\User\UserList::getFromParameters(Array)
#1 C:\Users\patil.vaish\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush\commands\user\user.drush.inc(355): Drush\User\UserList->__construct('admin')
#2 C:\Users\patil.vaish\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush\includes\command.inc(422): drush_user_password('admin')
#3 C:\Users\patil.vaish\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush\includes\command.inc(231): _drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
#4 C:\Users\patil.vaish\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush\includes\command.inc(199): drush_command('admin')
#5 C:\Users\patil.vaish\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush\lib\Drush\Boot\BaseBoot.php(67): drush_dispatch(Array)
#6 C:\Users\patil.vaish\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush\includes\preflight.inc(66): Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#7 C:\Users\patil.vaish\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush\drush.php(12): drush_main()
#8 {main}
```

How to solve the error?

Answer (score 0):

[This issue](https://github.com/droptica/docker-console/issues/25) suggests:

> If admin username in database is different than configuration ADMIN_USER [you get this error]
>
> ### Solution for drupal 7:
>
> ```
> self.run('sql-query --db-prefix "update {users} set name=\'%s\' where uid=1"' % self.config.DRUPAL['default']['ADMIN_USER'])
> ```
>
> ### Solution for drupal 8:
>
> ```
> self.run('sql-query --db-prefix "update {users_field_data} set name=\'%s\' where uid=1"' % self.config.DRUPAL['default']['ADMIN_USER'])
> ```